# Rationale in Scala linearization function

Tags: scala, traits

As far as I understand the Scala linearization function algorithm is right-first depth-first search, before eliminating all but the last occurrence of each trait in the resulting list.

There are two aspects of this algorithm that seem rather arbitrary to me:

- Why traits are explored first than classes and not vice versa ?
- Why traits are traversed right to left, instead of left to right ?

Are these arbitrary conventions, as good as any other one ? or maybe there is a rationale behind these design decisions ?

Note that my question concerns only the "horizontal" ordering of the algorithm.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Are these arbitrary conventions, as good as any other one?

No, these are not arbitrary. The linearization is done this way because it's the only way that will give you a sane *Method Resolution Order (MRO)*.

> Why traits are explored first than classes and not vice versa ?

This is only true for a given class definition, in that the traits it extends come before the class it extends. This follows from the fact that the super classes/traits are explored right-to-left—which brings us to your second point.

> Why traits are traversed right to left, instead of left to right ?

Here's a very simple motivating example for this.

```
type MyType = T1 with T2
// Creating new instance using alias
new MyType with T3
// Creating new instance directly
new T1 with T2 with T3
```

We would expect both instances in the example above to have the same linearization. When using type aliases, we "stack" additional traits on the right-hand-side, therefore we'd expect the traits on the right-hand-side to have highest precedence in the MRO, and therefore come first in the linearization.

Here's a quick example I came up with illustrating the linearization of traits and classes:

```
class Base { override def toString = "Base" }
trait A { abstract override def toString = "A " + super.toString }
trait B { abstract override def toString = "B " + super.toString }
trait C { abstract override def toString = "C " + super.toString }
trait D { abstract override def toString = "D " + super.toString }
trait E { abstract override def toString = "E " + super.toString }
trait F { abstract override def toString = "F " + super.toString }
class X extends Base with A with B { override def toString = "X " + super.toString }
class Y extends X with C with D { override def toString = "Y " + super.toString }
class Z extends Y with E with F { override def toString = "Z " + super.toString }
new Z
// res0: Z = Z F E Y D C X B A Base
```

You can see from the `toString` output that the linearization here is `Z F E Y D C X B A Base`, which is exactly what I'd expect with the given hierarchy. For example, since `Z` extends `Y`, which mixes-in the trait `C`, we would expect `Y`'s behaviors to come before `C`, but after `Z` and its mix-ins `E` and `F`.

A simple reference on this [Chapter 12 of Programming in Scala, First Edition: Traits](http://www.artima.com/pins1ed/traits.html#i-1280910181-1). (I don't think this has changed recently, so the first edition should still be accurate.)

Comment: Thanks for answering @DaoWen, still it is not that clear: "This is only true for a given class definition, in that the traits it extends come before the class it extends. " So do you mean in Scala I can also write something like: "class Z with E extends Y" ? and then Y will be looked before E in a super call ?

Comment: I still do not get the rationale for the right to left order. If I understood correctly, you say that when using type aliases, the alias will be replaced by its original definition when instantiating the type. This may make sense to me, but I think it is orthogonal to the right-to-left ordering convention. I can imagine another convention in which, after replacing type aliases for their definitions, super types are processed from left to right, and it does not seem worse or better than right to left processing. What I am missing here ?

Comment: @Sergio - For your first question, no, you can't put `extends` after `with`. My point was simply that superclasses and supertraits both follow the same right-to-left ordering constraint for a given class. As for my right-to-left example—when you type `new MyType with T3`, you're explicitly saying you want to add/override certain behaviors of `MyType` with those in `T3`. If the MRO left-to-right instead, then some behaviors from `T1` might take precedence instead. There would be no way to override the `T1` behaviors, and the `with T3` class would essentially be useless.